# Ajax HtmlEditor control has elements with  style='' on local and style='display:none' on host

Tags: asp.net, ajax, coding-style, controls, html-editor

I have strange problem with HtmlEditor ajax control.
I'm using .NET 4.0
Everything worked fine while I was testing my ASP.NET application on local computer, but when I published it on host, it does not work. Page is **not** breaking, but HtmlEditor is not displayed correctly. Instead of normaly displayed control, only 3 squers are displayed.
If I look the generated HTML code on local computer, elements of HtmlEditor have **style=""**, and HTML code generated on host has elements with **style="display:none;"**. I tried to set HtmlEditor's Visable and Enabled properties to value **true** but it didn't help.
Correct AjaxControlToolkit.dll is uploaded.
Anyone has a clue why this is happening?

My code looks like this:

```
 <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/Black.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="XXXXXX.aspx.cs" Inherits="XXXXXXX.Web.Admin.AdminArticle" %>
```

<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPages/Black.Master" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor"
TagPrefix="asp" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphMainContent" runat="server">

    <table class="entryTable">        
        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="litTitle" Text="Naslov" runat="server"></asp:Label>:
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" MaxLength="128"     CssClass="textEntry"> </asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ValidationGroup="New"
                ControlToValidate="txtTitle" ErrorMessage="XXXXXXXXXXX." Text="*" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" ControlToValidate="txtTitle"
                runat="server" ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{0,128}$" ErrorMessage="XXXXXXXXXX."
                Text="*" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="New" />
            </td>
        </tr>        

        <tr>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="litMainText" Text="Main Text" runat="server"></asp:Label>:
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <asp:Editor runat="server" ID="edtMainText" Height="300px" Width="495px"></asp:Editor>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ValidationGroup="New"
                ControlToValidate="edtMainText" ErrorMessage="XXXXXX." Text="*"
                Display="Dynamic"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator3" ControlToValidate="edtMainText"
                runat="server" ValidationExpression="^[\s\S]{0,30000}$" ErrorMessage="XXXXXXXXXX."
                Text="*" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="New" />
            </td>
        </tr>        
        <tr>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
                <br />
                <asp:Button ID="btnCreate" ValidationGroup="New" runat="server" Text="Create" OnClick="btnCreate_OnClick" />
                <asp:Button ID="btnClear" runat="server" Text="Clear" OnClick="btnClear_OnClick" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="ValidationSummary" runat="server" CssClass="failureNotification"
    ValidationGroup="New" />    
</asp:Content>

I hope I gave enough info.
Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the correct version of AjaxControlToolkit is available on hosted system.